# Static array of method pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, static, static-array

I'm facing an error I dont understand.

I try to create and use a static array of method pointers. The declaration in my class looks like this:

```
static void (Client::*packetHandler[Op::handledOpcodeMax - Op::handledOpcodeMin + 1])(QByteArray &data);
```

Initialization takes place in my .cpp files is like that:

```
void (Client::*packetHandler[Op::handledOpcodeMax - Op::handledOpcodeMin + 1])(QByteArray &data);
```

Here comes the troubles, in one of my Client's class method I try to use this methods pointers' array.
I tried several ways, for example :

```
(this->*packetHandler[_opcode])(data);
```

I said I didnt understand the problem, let me explain why. Running make on my code results in a proper compilation, tought, there is a problem when linking.

```
client.cpp:71: undefined reference to `Client::packetHandler'
```

This message is repeated 5 times.

Any help would be welcome.
Thank you.

Comment: statics are local to your translation unit. maybe an export would be in order.

Comment: would it be too obnoxious to tell you to use boost::function instead ?

Comment: I would strongly recommend a few typedefs to clean up that mess.

Comment: is there any chance few of the lines exists in a header file ?

Comment: @KerrekSB typedefs would make those cleaner, but not so funny.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe I don't really understand, the static keyword is in my header file only.`static void (Client::*packetHandler[Op::handledOpcodeMax - Op::handledOpcodeMin + 1])(QByteArray &data);` is in my header file.
@George Well, yes because I want to do it on my own (learning purpose) :P. @Kerrek Maybe later, I need to clearly understand what's going on :D. @Mellowcandle Well, the first line belongs to client.hpp

Comment: try (this->packetHandler[_opcode])(data); instead of going indirect through the table entry (i.e., not (this->*packetHandler[_opcode])(data);)

Comment: can you post the full command line used in compilation and linking? I mean fully build log.. other hint is to create a local variable of appropriate func-ptr-type, say myvar and init with correct ptr, and then change `(this->*packetHandler[_opcode])(data);` to `myvar(data);`, then see where the error is.

Comment: @thekashyap I tried to do that: `void (Client::*ptr)(QByteArray &); ptr = packetHandler[_opcode];` This gives me `undefined reference to Client::packetHandler'.` I guess that the problem comes from array initialization, I mean, it seems that `void (Client::*packetHandler[Op::handledOpcodeMax - Op::handledOpcodeMin + 1])(QByteArray &data);` doesnt make the array a static member of the client class. Or something like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`void (Client::*packetHandler[Op::handledOpcodeMax - Op::handledOpcodeMin + 1])(QByteArray &data);` declares a global variable named `packetHandler`. You want to define your class variable, which needs an extra `Client::` like so:

```
void (Client::*Client::packetHandler[Op::handledOpcodeMax - Op::handledOpcodeMin + 1])(QByteArray &data);
```

Comment: Haha thank you Neil. I was thinking of something like this after @thekashyap comment. I tried `void (Client::Client::*packetHandler[Op::handledOpcodeMax - Op::handledOpcodeMin + 1])(QByteArray &data);`. Bad luck with `*` position :D. Thanks :)

Comment: Just goes to show how important Kerrek SB's comment abt typedefing is.. :)

Answer (score 0):

`Client::*packetHandler` is a member function pointer that points to a member function named `Client::packetHandler`.  I'm not sure how to make a member function pointer that points to an arbitrary member function which is what you seem to want to do.  I think George is right.  You should consider using something like `boost::function` or `std::tr1::function` or write your own member function wrapper class.

Comment: To make a function pointer pointing to whatever member function you want is simple, you have nothing special to do. My problem here is that I want this array to be a static element of my class. Removing the `static` keyword in the header file makes the compilation and linking work.